# File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/functions RAILS 4.1.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I have tried everything and nothing seems to be working. could one kindly advise how i can rectify this issue

error message:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/functions.
```

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.0' 

gem 'rails', '4.1.10'
gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.7'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem "foundation-rails"
gem "sass-rails"
gem 'compass'
gem 'zurb-foundation'
gem 'simple_form'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'devise'
gem "ransack"
gem "polyamorous"
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'acts_as_commentable'
gem "cocoon"
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'social-share-button'
gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'
gem 'public_activity'
gem 'foundation-datetimepicker-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'stripe'
gem "stripe_event"
gem 'cloudinary'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'
gem 'ckeditor'
gem 'impressionist'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'mailcatcher'
  gem "better_errors"
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'unicorn',        '4.8.3'
end
```

terminal:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/functions.
Load paths:
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/babel-source-5.8.35/lib
  /Users/ARTLoe/00_GitH/00_Projects/recruitmentAfrica_app/app/assets/images
  /Users/ARTLoe/00_GitH/00_Projects/recruitmentAfrica_app/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/00_GitH/00_Projects/recruitmentAfrica_app/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/ARTLoe/00_GitH/00_Projects/recruitmentAfrica_app/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/00_GitH/00_Projects/recruitmentAfrica_app/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/ckeditor-4.2.4/app/assets/images
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/ckeditor-4.2.4/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/ckeditor-4.2.4/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/ckeditor-4.2.4/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cloudinary-1.9.1/vendor/assets/html
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cloudinary-1.9.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-6.0.1/app/assets/images
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-6.0.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-6.0.1/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/foundation-datetimepicker-rails-0.2.4/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/foundation-datetimepicker-rails-0.2.4/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/social-share-button-1.1.0/app/assets/images
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/social-share-button-1.1.0/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/social-share-button-1.1.0/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cocoon-1.2.11/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/font-awesome-rails-4.7.0.4/app/assets/fonts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/font-awesome-rails-4.7.0.4/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/foundation-rails-6.4.3.0/vendor/assets/_vendor
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/foundation-rails-6.4.3.0/vendor/assets/js
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/foundation-rails-6.4.3.0/vendor/assets/scss
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jquery-turbolinks-2.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jquery-rails-3.1.5/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.1/lib/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/turbolinks-source-5.1.0/lib/assets/javascripts
/Users/ARTLoe/00_GitH/00_Projects/recruitmentAfrica_app/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss:58
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:67:in `rescue in import'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:45:in `import'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:314:in `visit_import'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:162:in `block in visit'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:162:in `visit'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:171:in `block in visit_children'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:183:in `with_environment'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:170:in `visit_children'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:190:in `visit_root'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:161:in `visit'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:10:in `visit'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/engine.rb:284:in `render'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.7/lib/sass/rails/template.rb:47:in `evaluate'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/tilt-2.0.8/lib/tilt/template.rb:109:in `render'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy_tilt_processor.rb:25:in `call'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:200:in `dfs'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/functions.
Load paths:
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/babel-source-5.8.35/lib
  /Users/ARTLoe/00_GitH/00_Projects/recruitmentAfrica_app/app/assets/images
  /Users/ARTLoe/00_GitH/00_Projects/recruitmentAfrica_app/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/00_GitH/00_Projects/recruitmentAfrica_app/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/ARTLoe/00_GitH/00_Projects/recruitmentAfrica_app/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/00_GitH/00_Projects/recruitmentAfrica_app/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/ckeditor-4.2.4/app/assets/images
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/ckeditor-4.2.4/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/ckeditor-4.2.4/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/ckeditor-4.2.4/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cloudinary-1.9.1/vendor/assets/html
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cloudinary-1.9.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-6.0.1/app/assets/images
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-6.0.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-6.0.1/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/foundation-datetimepicker-rails-0.2.4/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/foundation-datetimepicker-rails-0.2.4/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/social-share-button-1.1.0/app/assets/images
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/social-share-button-1.1.0/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/social-share-button-1.1.0/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cocoon-1.2.11/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/font-awesome-rails-4.7.0.4/app/assets/fonts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/font-awesome-rails-4.7.0.4/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/foundation-rails-6.4.3.0/vendor/assets/_vendor
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/foundation-rails-6.4.3.0/vendor/assets/js
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/foundation-rails-6.4.3.0/vendor/assets/scss
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jquery-turbolinks-2.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jquery-rails-3.1.5/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.1/lib/assets/javascripts
  /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/turbolinks-source-5.1.0/lib/assets/javascripts
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:65:in `import'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:314:in `visit_import'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:162:in `block in visit'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:162:in `visit'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:171:in `block in visit_children'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:183:in `with_environment'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:170:in `visit_children'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:190:in `visit_root'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:161:in `visit'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:10:in `visit'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/engine.rb:284:in `render'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.7/lib/sass/rails/template.rb:47:in `evaluate'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/tilt-2.0.8/lib/tilt/template.rb:109:in `render'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy_tilt_processor.rb:25:in `call'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:200:in `dfs'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: `File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/functions` How do your files look like? Do they contain this path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you run `rails g foundation:install` after upgrading foundation-rails to a new major version? I lost a lot of time on this same issue today until I realized that the new major version shifted the structure around. Running the installation command (and figuring out what conflicts it should override) fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

I have run up against this problem periodically using 'foundation-rails' gem, and I think I just discovered the cause of it in my case.  Comparing a project where it was working and one where it wasn't, I noticed that the application stylesheet lacked the .scss extension.  Simply renaming **application.css -> application.css.scss** did the trick for me.